# Diagonal morphism and adjunction

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Hello,

I have the following problem:

if I have an elliptic curve $E$ over some field and consider the diagonal morphism

$\Delta: E \rightarrow E\times E$,

does then hold the following:

the adjunction morphism

$\Delta^* \Delta_* \mathcal{O}_E\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_E$

is an isomorphism?

Thank you!

Comment: The diagonal of an elliptic curve in never open. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diagonal of an elliptic curve (or more generally of a seprarated scheme) is a closed immersion. Thus the following more general result answers your question affirmatively: Let $i\colon Y \to X$ be a closed immersion and let ${\mathscr G}$ be a quasi-coherent ${\mathscr O}_Y$-module. Then the adjunction morphism $i^*i_*{\mathscr G} \to {\mathscr G}$ is an isomorphism.

The question is local on $X$ and we may assume that $X = {\rm Spec} A$ is affine. Then $Y = {\rm Spec} (A/{\mathfrak a})$ for an ideal ${\mathfrak a}$ of $A$, and ${\mathscr G}$ corresponds to an $(A/{\mathfrak a})$-module $M$, i.e. to an $A$-module $M$ with ${\mathfrak a} M = 0$ and the adjunction morphism corresponds to the isomorphism $A/{\mathfrak a} \otimes_A M \to M$.